# What's an IDE for a PHP + JS(extJS) development that supports ctrl+click?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, extjs

im currently adding features to an existing web application made from CI (php) and ExtJS (js).
I'm a total newb to Extjs and it frustrates me how I can't trace code because I don't know where to look for declarations.

Now are there IDEs out there that supports ctrl+click (go to declaration)? I'm sure this will save me a lot of time!

Thanks.

Comment: I have been using it for years, but I use ext2js and it isn't set up properly. I use notepad++ And debug bar to trace, if you have non-minified code you can usually see the offending javascript. Although I would love to know if there is a better way.

Comment: PHPStorm/WebStorm from [jetbrains.com](http://jetbrains.com). Warning: These may make you hate yourself for suffering with Eclipse/Notepad++/(insert your current favorite IDE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PHPStorm` supports  it     too.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: What IDE support? PHPStorm support. Why it should be comment?

Comment: Your answer doesn't live up to the quality guidelines. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

Comment: I actually tried PHPStorm but it's just to heavy (the application) for me :/

Comment: so far the best IDE (for me) when it comes to ctrl+click functionality :) (although one heavy IDE, sometimes heavier than Eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

I use Netbeans 7.2 IDE and it does support Ctrl+click
http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html

Comment: I can't afford to download as big as netbeans but, just to make sure, does it support ctrl+click for javascript? I need that support more than PHP support. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

I used to use netbeans, eclipse and all those IDE's but they were so slow...

Sublime Text 2 is LIGHTNING fast. There are so many extensions (packages) you can install on it (for example CodeIgniter snippets -> I use CodeIgniter myself).

You can check a review [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPhhC31b8Sw).

For as ExtJs... I worked with ExtJs on my previous work, but I've never found an IDE that supports ExtJs.

Comment: Sorry but I need JS support more than PHP support. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well, you can also install like JS packages... It's just that an IDE that supports ExtJs is hard to find.